# Change background and text color in HTML

Tags: html, css

how do I change my background and text color? as you can see, I already put the background color black but it didn't change the color. I want to make a dark mode version. thanks. also, don't worry about the content, it's for demonstration only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {text-align: center;}
p {text-align: left;}
div {text-align: left;}
.left {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:black

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>UwU</h1>
<p>you just got uwu.</p>
<p>say uwu after you saw master uwu for ton of luck UwU</p>
<div>UwU.</div>
<a href="D:\Untitled-1.html" target="_self">Link to page 2</a>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="avatar" style="width:300px">

</body>
</html>
    <style type ="text/css" >
      .footer{ 
          position: fixed;     
          text-align: left;    
          bottom: 0px; 
          width: 100%;
          color: black;
      }  
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="footer">Made by rama 4/6/2020
       <a href="D:\new rama project uwu.html" target="_self">use light mode</a>
       </div>
       
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the properties to the wrong elements, if you aim to have a total dark mode, you should target the most outer element: the `body`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body.darkmode{
 background-color:black;
 color: white;
}
h1 {text-align: center;}
p {text-align: left;}
div {text-align: left;}
.left {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:black
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="darkmode">

<h1>UwU</h1>
<p>you just got uwu.</p>
<p>say uwu after you saw master uwu for ton of luck UwU</p>
<div>UwU.</div>
<a href="D:\Untitled-1.html" target="_self">Link to page 2</a>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="avatar" style="width:300px">

</body>
</html>
    <style type ="text/css" >
      .footer{ 
          position: fixed;     
          text-align: left;    
          bottom: 0px; 
          width: 100%;
          color: black;
      }  
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="footer">Made by rama 4/6/2020
       <a href="D:\new rama project uwu.html" target="_self">use light mode</a>
       </div>
       
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have applied `background-color:black` in `.left` class which is not mentioned anywhere in the HTML. You need to apply `background-color` as `black` to the `body` to have darker theme

```html
body{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:black

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please check this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dark-mood').click(function(){
   $('body').css("background-color","#000");
      $('body').css("color","#fff");
  });
 });
```

```css
h1 {text-align: center;}
p {text-align: left;}
div {text-align: left;}
.left {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:black

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="dark-mood">Click here to see dark mood</a>
<h1>UwU</h1>
<p>you just got uwu.</p>
<p>say uwu after you saw master uwu for ton of luck UwU</p>
<div>UwU.</div>
<a href="D:\Untitled-1.html" target="_self">Link to page 2</a>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="avatar" style="width:300px">

</body>
</html>
    <style type ="text/css" >
      .footer{ 
          position: fixed;     
          text-align: left;    
          bottom: 0px; 
          width: 100%;
          color: black;
      }  
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="footer">Made by rama 4/6/2020
       <a href="D:\new rama project uwu.html" target="_self">use light mode</a>
       </div>
       
   </body>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

body {

background-color : black;

}

Comment: Hi HackerBoy, you should try to answer in a more complete way, adding reasons so that the poster could better understand the answer (even when trivial). Also, it's good practice to add styling to your answer

Comment: I will keep that in my mind thanks for the suggestion.